# python: selected socket doesn't return anything

Tags: python, sockets, select

Here is a piece of my code, not-necessary code is hidden.

```
if sock_active:
    r,w,x=select.select([conn],[],[],0.1)
    if r:
        try:
            logging.debug("Waiting for socks")
            sockdata=conn.recv(BUF_SIZE)
            logging.debug("Recevied data")
            if sockdata is None:
                raise ConnectionError("socket closed")
            else:
                recvcache+=sockdata.decode()
                logging.debug("Network Cache:%s"%recvcache)
```

Now the problem is when the socket has recevied data once, it will continuously output "Waiting for socks","Recevied data" and "Network Cache:"

Is something I understood wrong?

==UPDATE==

So zero-length messages can be "selected". What I meant to do is to receive not zero-length message, what should I do? And is there any difference between `recv` blocking the thread and `recv` get zero-length message?

Additional info:

I use `sock.listen()` to create a listening socket and accept connections from clients, then I start a new thread and pass the accpeted socket to the new thread. All messages is ended by`\n`. what I expected to recevie is something like `<COMMAND> <ARGS>\n`

Thanks.

Comment: So what's the problem? It seems to work well; sockets do not prohibit zero-length messages and `select` is just a guarantee that `recv` won't block the thread. Please add more information. (And shouldn't `else` be a part of `try else` statement?)

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Thanks, I have edited my question.

Comment: Yep. It's not a common situation, but it [can happen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) (see `RETURN VALUE` section). Given this, I'd suggest you to expand your question, e. g., what do you expect to `recv`, how do you create a socket, who sends the data?

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Thanks a lot. More info are added